# What exactly is different between a string and an FString in Unreal C++?

Tags: architecture, unreal-4

Sorry, maybe a noob question, I did a quick google search and couldn't find what I was looking for.  I have two related questions about FString.

1. Does regular C++ Have this, or is this an Unreal term.  (I know python has a variable called FString).
2. What makes FString different from the String variable?

thnx.  It's not very necessary for development, but I'm just curious why Unreal uses FString instead of String.

Comment: I also recommend you to discover this [link](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/ProgrammingAndScripting/ProgrammingWithCPP/UnrealArchitecture/StringHandling/index.html) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FString` (and all types that are prefixed with `U`,`F`,`T` etc.) are custom Unreal Types.
They have special behaviour and work hand-in-hand with Unreal's Typesystem and Garbage Collection.

Use `string` and other raw types if you want to program plain C++ Code. Use the Unreal Types if you want to interface with your Game.

Comment: thanks, that clears it up.  =)